# My boss is not allowing student employees anymore

Tags: careers, career-switch

I'm a full time worker, in retail.  It's really more like thrift...anyways, we're always short on people in my area-- which is, being a cashier.  It's pretty stressful dealing with customers but at least I get to move around the store.
 My boss says that they will not be hiring anymore students because she is tired of employees not being able to be completely flexible.  I understand this and I was never a student; well, enrolled in classroom setting.
  So, just as I want to take one class towards a two year degree, I am told I may or may not be allowed time off to attend and/or get study hours. 
  I am looking for another job or to move up in the company. One of my supervisors is actually taking classes.
   Is there anything else I can do to try to get a degree other than online classes?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: Apply for the store manager position.  Looks like it will be opening up, shortly.

Comment: Whatever the situation is, no retail job is worth stalling your career for. Pursue what has the best potential for tomorrow, if they try and tell you no keep in mind they work for you as much as you work for them. You can fire them just like they can fire you, and some bosses are just worth firing.

Answer (score 1):

This will really depend on the specifics of your workplace and your contract.  If your contract is for a "Day shift cashier" your employer probably can't fire you for not being available nights, which opens up night classes for you.  Most likely the contract is sufficiently vague that your employer would be able to make your life difficult.  If this is the case then you have a work-life balance issue and should look for other employment where management is accepting of the fact that you aspire for a career at some point.

Your future is brighter with an education, make good life decisions that facilitate this.

Comment: If @Emma is in the U.S., then she likely has no employment contract and can be fired at will, for nearly any reason.

Comment: @Dogweather None at at would be plenty vague enough for the employer to make life difficult.  Since she hasn't stated her country answers should refrain from being American specific.  Region specific advice is often given freely around here without first confirming that it applies.

Answer (score 1):

**Your future is more important than your right now**

First, before I go into this further on what your options are in the event your employer takes the nuclear option of choose between your job and your education. Your future is the top priority don't let a job stall your career. Now I'll step off my soap box and back to your question!

**School from home / online**

This is a good option for self motivators who are organized. If you're not both of these online will be very difficult, not impossible, but understand it'll take a larger personal investment than traditional in person school will. (stuff like setting alarms to say you're on "school time" and disallowing distractions like tv, radio, internet, games, etc during those times.)

You just need to find the right school and program and go for it. (Note many online degrees require you to take a proctored exam in person at the end. You often get some flexibility in scheduling it, but not always. That said just schedule a personal day to deal with it well in advance. (If that's unacceptable, well future > now. You'll just have to see how they respond when you do it)

**Not all schools are made equal**

You need to be VERY careful in your selection of schools. There are some really terrible bottom feeders who will give you degrees that aren't worth the paper their printed on. That said all major universities are properly accredited and worth considering as are most state colleges and community colleges, but you should still verify this. When dealing with tech schools, online only schools, etc approach with caution, some are good, most are terrible.

Also note not all accreditations are equal. I advise speaking with an admissions person or councilor at your local university and ask what accreditation they require to allow students to transfer classes in and any school without that accreditation should be removed from consideration.

When pursuing a school any school that starts talking about how you'll pay them before worrying about IF the school is even what you want you should immediately remove from consideration. You should also remove any school that pushes you to "sign up now before it's too late!" or has a "waiting list but might be able to squeeze you in" these are high pressure sales tactics used by the worst of the worst. (not trying to be scary, just don't want you to waste years of your life and your hard earned money on garbage)

**Is online right for you?**

Most classes online are fine and rewarding. Some classes taking online is a joke and not going to help you in real life. (Looking at you Speech / Public Speaking!) Some classes can be extremely challenging online (Math is easily the worst to deal with online) you also miss the "college life" which I feel holds a certain unspoken value in learning to deal with people. That said there are times we simply can't take time out of our lives to goto college in person so it is what it is. Determine what would be the best plan of action for now to help out future you, future you depends on the choices you make today.